# Template class pointer c++ declaration

Tags: c++, class, templates, pointers, declaration

```
template <typename T>
class Node
{...};

int main
{
    Node* ptr;
    ptr = new Node<int>;
}
```

Will fail to compile I have to to declare the pointer as

```
Node<int>* ptr;
```

Why do I have to specify the type when declaring a pointer I haven't created the class yet, why does the compiler have to know what type it will be pointing to. And is it not possible to create a generic pointer and decide afterwards what type I want to assign it.

Comment: It hasn't appeared in any answer so far and I don't think it deserves writing one, but here's an important bit: `Node` is not a type. It is a template. It's true that is a *class* template, but only things like `Node<int>`, `Node<double>` or `Node<Node<void> >` are types; `Node` will forever be a template and there are only pointers to types. No such thing as a pointer to template.

Comment: That is such an important bit that it does deserve to be in an answer rather than just in a comment.

Comment: Shouldn't the correct syntax be be `Node<int>* ptr = new Node<int>();` ? I think `()` should be present.

Comment: @enthusiasticgeek it is optional

Answer (score 41):

Templating resolves types at compile-time. When you assign the new `Node<int>` object to it, the pointer must know at compile-time what type exactly it is.

`Node<int>` and `Node<std::vector>` can be very different in the binaries (the binary layout of your object changes completely according the template parameter) so it doesn't make any sense to have an unresolved pointer type to a template.

You should define first a common parent class for your nodes:

```
class NodeBase
{ ... }

template<typename ValueT>
  class Node : public NodeBase
{
 ...
};

NodeBase* ptr;
```

Comment: @Mike, you managed to rewrite my complete answer. Are you sure that was you intention?

Comment: All I did was add backticks around `Node<int>` and `Node<std::vector>` to format them as code rather than text. Without that formatting, the sentence read "Node and Node can be very different", which didn't make sense.

Comment: @Yola, I'm not exactly sure what do you mean here? The question wasn't concerning the overhead of virtual function calls. Virtual functions have no alternative in certain situation, namely when it comes to runtime function resolving.

Answer (score 11):

The simple answer is because C++ uses (fairly) strict static type
checking.  `Node<int>` is a completely unrelated type to `Node<double>`,
and when the compiler sees `ptr->doSomething()`, it has to know whether
to call `Node<int>::doSomething()` or `Node<double>::doSomething()`.

If you do need some sort of dynamic generality, where the 
actual type `ptr` will point to will only be known at runtime, you need
to define a base class, and derive from that.  (It's a fairly common
idiom for a class template to derive from a non-template base, precisely
so that the generality in the pointers can be resolved at runtime.)

Answer (score 5):

> Why do I have to specify the type when declaring a pointer I haven't created the class yet, why does the compiler have to know what type it will be pointing to.

There are lots of things you're allowed to do with a pointer, just to list a very few:

- call one of many functions based on the pointer's type
- index from it (on the assumption that it points to the first elements in a contiguous array of such objects)
- take the size of the pointed-to object
- pass it to a template where the pointer-type is a parameter

For the compiler to generate code to do these efficiently, it needs to know the type of the pointer.  If it defered the decisions until it saw the type of the pointer, then it would need to either:

- compile efficient code for every possible type the pointer might later take (making a hugely bloated program), or
- create inefficient code that can handle all the possible types through some worst-case pessimistic clumsy behaviours, or
- embed a copy of itself (the compiler) into your C++ program so it can complete it's job when it's got the necessary information - that would make every trivial program huge (and slow)

> And is it not possible to create a generic pointer and decide afterwards what type I want to assign it.

Kind of... you have many options:

- use a `void*`, but before it can meaningfully operate on the pointed-to-type again you'll need to manually cast it back to that type: in your case that means recording somewhere what it was then having separate code for every possibility
- use `boost::any<>` - pretty much like a `void*`, but with safety built in
- use `boost::variant<>` - much safer and more convenient, but you have to list the possible pointed-to types when you create the pointer
- use a runtime polymorphic family of objects and virtual dispatch... this is classic Object Oriented Programming... you have a pointer to an "abstract" `Node` that declares the shared functions and member data you'd use to operate on any particular type of node, then the templated `Node` class derives from that abstract `Node` and implements type-specific versions of the functions.  These are then called via a pointer to the base class using `virtual` functions.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you create any kind of object (including pointers) in C++, the full type of the object must be known. There is no such type in your code as `Node`, so you can't create instances of pointers to it. You need to rethink how you are designing and writing your code.

Answer (score 1):

As both Neil Butterworth and Luc Danton noted, you can't have a pointer of type Node* because Node is not a type. It is a template. Yes, Node is a class template, but that *class* here just qualifies the kind of template. One way to look at it: Just as classes and instances of classes are very different things, so too are templates and template instantiations. It is those template instantiations such as Node that are classes. The class template is some other kind of beast.