# Wrapping templated objects elegantly in Cython

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, dry, cython

This is similar to [this question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400469/c-class-in-fused-type) but it never got any solutions, and I have at least a workaround for the problem, as inelegant as it is.

I am trying to wrap a templated class, `Point<_T,__Scale>`, where `_T=int,float...` and `__Scale` is an int. Now the compiler will generate a separate class for each template value used, but the classes are not related in any way. However, the classes share all their methods, mostly operator overloads for `!=<>*&/|`, and getters.

In Cython, the only way I have been able to wrap `Point<_T,__Scale>` is to provide a cdef class for each variation. It works, but results in a lot of copy-pasted code. I would like to know if there is way to share the code between these template class wrappers. Note that I am following the cython method for wrapping described in the tutorials, where a wrapper class holds a `*thisptr` to the c-object it is wrapping.

```
// c++ header
template<_T,__Scale>
class Point
{
    Point(_T _x, _T _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {};
    // copy constructor
    template<typename _NT> Point(const Point<_NT, __Scale> &pt) : x( (_T)pt.x ), y( (_T)pt.y ) {};
    _t x, y;
    bool operator == (const Point<_T,__Scale> &pos) const
    bool operator != (const Point<_T,__Scale> &pos) const
    // and many more operators
}

typedef Point<int,1> PointA
typedef Point<int,8> PointB
... //additional typedefs

# cython interface with c++ (not shown: cdef extern from ...)
cdef cppclass Point[_T,__Scale]:
    Point(_T _x, _T _y)
    Point[_NT] Point(const Point[_NT,0] &pt)
    _T x
    _T y
    bint operator == (const Point[_T,__Scale] &pos) const
    bint operator != (const Point[_T,__Scale] &pos) const

# cython wrapper to interface with python (this is where it gets messy)
cdef class pyPointA:
    cdef PointA* thisptr
    def __cinit__(self, int x, int y):
        self.thisptr = new PointA(x,y)
    # everything in this class below this line is copied
    def x(self, setX = None):
        if(setX is None):
            return self.thisptr.x
        else:
            self.thisptr.x = setX

    def y(self, setY = None):
        if(setY is None):
            return self.thisptr.y
        else:
            self.thisptr.y = setY
    # and many more operators

cdef class pyPointB
    cdef PointB* thisptr
    def __cinit__(self, int x, int y):
        self.thisptr = new PointB(x,y)
    # everything in this class below this line is copied
    def x(self, setX = None):
        if(setX is None):
            return self.thisptr.x
        else:
            self.thisptr.x = setX

    def y(self, setY = None):
        if(setY is None):
            return self.thisptr.y
        else:
            self.thisptr.y = setY
    # and many more operators

...
#continue for additional point types
```

Here is what I have tried:

- Abstract cython base class to inherit the others from. Ok, but each template type needs different pointers.
- Store `*thisptr` as `*void`. How to deal with the casting?
- encapsulate `thisptr` by retrieving it using a getter `getPtr()`, but still am forced into a single return type. Cannot declare as Python function, because c pointers cannot be wrapped in python objects.
- write several method that return the correct pointer type, then the `getPtr()` method returns the right getter for each method to call, to get the pointer from. Unfortunately, only c-functions can return pointers, and they cannot be returned: compiler complains 'not found'.
- Same as above, except the `getPtr()` method returns the string name of the getter function, which then we can use `getattr()` to recall. But cdef method is unable to be found in Python using `getattr()`.

Comment: Maybe you want this? [Cython template documentation](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#templates)

Comment: I went through that and it seems to be a case of writing code in cython that will compile to c++ and interface with vector, but I want to make a wrapper class that is capable of being called from python code.

Comment: May I ask for a http://www.sscce.org/ ?

Comment: ratiotile, I think @aruisdante's link contains all you need, and I miss the point of your comment. Can you post a MWE as hivert asks?

Comment: @Flebool: isn't this now called a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? ;-)

Comment: @aruisdante,@flebool: added code example. Cython templates are used to generate c/c++ code, but I do not know how to use them on Python classes. Indeed, I doubt it is even possible.

Comment: Cython templates allow you to interface this piece of C++ templated code from cython. Then, you can write a module for python written in cython that exposes your `Point` template to python. At runtime in `__cinit__` you will decide which type `<_T,__Scale>` of Point you will want, and will dynamically allocate the instance with `self.thisptr = new Point[int,6](x,y)`. It SHOULD work, but I have never used it. Look at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342464/template-class-pointer-c-declaration) for how to hold a pointer to a templated class.

Comment: @flebool: that only works when `self.thisptr` is defined as `cdef Point[int,6] *thisptr`, which then cannot be assigned another variant eg. `self.thisptr = new Point[int,7]` would not compile.

Comment: See the link. Quoting, "You should define first a common parent class.." and then `self.thisptr` will be a pointer to that parent class. Check the most voted answer.

Comment: I don't see what you are getting at here. The linked question is in C++, and I am trying to wrap a precompiled library to be called from python. I only have c++ headers to the library. Maybe you could elaborate more with some example code?

Comment: Now I see. I thought you could add the parent class on the C++ side, and then inherit the templated class Point from that parent class, again in C++ space. But if you can't touch the C++ side of things you can't do this (you just mentioned it now anyway).

Comment: This is actually a bit confusing. How come a precompiled library exposes a template?

Comment: Yes, the .h file exposes a templated class as I have described in my question. OTOH the [STL containers also expose templated classes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/vector).

Comment: The STL is not a precompiled library.

Comment: Ok, bad example, but one does not simply go into STL or Boost and change things around... I need a way to accomplish the task of wrapping template class in python without code duplication.

Comment: I agree, you should not change things around in the STL or Boost. I said "if you can't touch the C++ side of things you can't do this". It is just very odd that a precompiled library exposes a templated interface, I wondered how they manage to do that.

Comment: By definition, if it's a template in C++, it's in the header. For exactly the reason that it would be impossible to pre-compile a templated interface.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there isn't going to be a perfectly seamless way of exposing a templated class to Python without a lot of work/clever trickery. This is because Python simply doesn't have an analog to a generic since, by definition of being a dynamically typed language, everything is already 'generic'. There's nothing to do static analysis on to determine what type instantiations to compile. You are going to have to manually wrap every instantiation type you intend to use in your code, or figure out a clever way to make the actual type unneeded at runtime.

Comment: It's a sad day when C++ turns out to be more powerful than Python. I also cannot figure out how to do `namespace foo:` in Python.

Comment: @flebool : if you look at the [code of the standard library for map](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.1/stl__tree_8h-source.html) (in G++ 4.8 version) then you see that the handling of rebalancing of red-black tree (class `_Rb_tree_node_base`) is provided by non template functions `_Rb_tree_insert_and_rebalance` which are precompiled.

Comment: @hivert thanks for the example, I think I now get what sort of code can handle templated types and be precompiled at the same time.

Comment: Attempted solution: use a `.pxi` file to hold duplicated code, and `include "file.pxi"` it into the separate classes to wrap each template instance. Support: ["The include statement can appear anywhere in your Cython file and at any indentation level"](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/language_basics.html#how-do-i-use-it) Failure: compile error "cannot include at that location". Are the Cython Docs incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty with this is that the templates are required to be instantiated at C compile time...and of course in C++ there's no common "superclass" for the various template instantiations.

Typically what I would suggest in this situation is using a template engine such as jinja2 to generate all permutations of classes you're interested in.